# Would/Do you mind?

Tags: grammar, clauses, subjunctives, conditionals, if

After would/do you mind, which of the following is correct (for each 3 of them)?

1. Would you mind if she **come**/**comes** +...?
2. Would you mind me to **tell**/**telling** +...?
3. Would you mind if I **leave**/**left** +...?
   For each item, Which of the two is correct and any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Your intended meaning of (2) isn't clear. _Would you mind telling me...?_ or _Would you mind if I told [someone else]?_

Comment: I want to say the second one: Would you mind if I... Can the second one be used to carry this meaning?

Comment: _To tell_ is wrong. _Would you mind me/my telling him...?_

Comment: So any ideas about other parts as well?

Answer (score 1):

We often ask 'Do you mind?' about something we are about to do anyway, as a mild apology for inconveniencing someone.

> D'you mind if I squeeze past you to get to the window?

'Would you mind?' is a bit more tentative and therefore more polite.

> Would you mind if she came along too?

> Would you mind if I left early to catch my bus?

Comment: So, would you mind if she come is incorrect? Just past tense?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect in two ways. The present tense is _she comes_, and _would_ is the conditional so it takes the past tense here.